# Removing type from a dynamic assembly

Tags: c#, typebuilder, assemblybuilder

I created a new type using `AssemblyBuilder` / `ModuleBuilder` / `TypeBuilder`. Is there a way to remove this type at a later time from the same runtime?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't modify/unload assembly after it is loaded at run-time.